# Find wave function satisfying Schroedinger Equation $[\frac{1}{2m}(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla-\frac{e} {c}A(r))^2+V(r)]\psi^{'}(r) = E\psi^{'}(r)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

Given an "ordinary" wave function $\psi(r)$ that satisfies the "ordinary" stationary Schrodinger equation $[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\Delta+V(r)]\psi(r)= E\psi(r)$, I want to construct a wave function $\psi^{'}(r)$ that satisfies the "electromagnetic" Schroedinger Equation $[\frac{1}{2m}(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla-\frac{e} {c}A(r))^2+V(r)]\psi^{'}(r) = E\psi^{'}(r)$, where $A(r)$ is a vector potential.

Okay so my approach is to choose a phase function $\alpha(r)$ such that $[-i\hbar\nabla- \frac{e}{c}A(r)]e^{i\alpha(r)}\psi(r)=e^{i\alpha(r)}[-i\hbar\nabla\psi(r)]$ But to be honest I don't really know how to handle the elctromagnetic Hamiltonian in Quantum Mechanics... What's the angle here?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are aiming for. Even with the simplest electric/magnetic fields, one is often forced to consider perturbation theory or semi-classical methods in order to estimate stationary wave functions. Also, you might want to post this in physicsexchange. The complexity of the problem will also heavily depend on $V$, $A$, the spatial region of interest and which quantum numbers or degrees of freedom are you taking into account, among other things. Maybe what you want to see is that the phase that you have introduced there can be compensated with a gauge tranformation?